# SQLBoiler get table name for Join

Tags: sql, go, orm, sqlboiler

I am trying to follow the examples in sqlboiler (https://github.com/volatiletech/sqlboiler). But, I can't find a way to get the table name used in the Inner join query.

```
users, err := models.Users(
  Select("id", "name"),
  InnerJoin("credit_cards c on c.user_id = users.id"),
  Where("age > ?", 30),
  AndIn("c.kind in ?", "visa", "mastercard"),
  Or("email like ?", `%aol.com%`),
  GroupBy("id", "name"),
  Having("count(c.id) > ?", 2),
  Limit(5),
  Offset(6),
).All(ctx, db)
```

In this example, if, instead of hard-coding the name (`credit_cards`), I could provide the table name, it'd be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Not familiar with sqlboiler, but I know that most ORMs do not really have support for variable column or table names. However you can use string interpolation (`fmt.Sprintf`), but make sure that you are very careful about checking for valid values since this can lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities. (You can sanitize by checking that the given value is one of a select few).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table names are in the `TableNames` struct, which is in the file `boil_table_names.go`

So, I think it would be something like this `models.TableNames.CreditCards`